# converting from Swift to Objective C, why does this code work only once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a very simple objective c code here that grabs the selected date from the date picker and attach that as a variable (_labelllll) to a label. It works for the first time only. If I try a different date it wouldn't work again. I also have the working code in swift which works fine but I need to write it in Objective C properly. Can anybody help? appreciate it.

**Objective C Code:**

```
- (IBAction)didDateChamge:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
    NSString *dayOfTheWeek = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [_labelllll setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dayOfTheWeek]];

}
```

Swift Code: 
[image]

Comment: Please look at your code `sender.date` != `[NSDate date]`

Comment: You are passing different values to `stringFromDate:` - in Objective-C you are sending `[NSDate date]`, while in Swift you are sending `sender.date`

Comment: Everytime you pass [NSDate date]. replace - (IBAction)didDateChamge:(id)sender with - (IBAction)didDateChamge:(UIDatePicker *)sender and change this line NSString *dayOfTheWeek = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; to NSString *dayOfTheWeek = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sender.date];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
- (IBAction)didDateChamge:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
    NSString *dayOfTheWeek = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sender.date];
    [_labelllll setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dayOfTheWeek]];

}
```

You need to change method signature and use  sender.date to get selected date.

Comment: It should be `(UIDatePicker*)` !

Comment: @AliRJ when using stand alone local day of week you should use `"cccc"` instead of `"EEEE"`